# How to add different elements from multiple arrays

Tags: php, mysql

I am building a small PHP/MySQL system to track transfers of product between different store locations within the same company.  Each store will enter their transfers into the database.  Then the accountant should be able to pull a summary report at the end of the month.

The information is being stored in the database like this:

```
   ID | Transfer Date | Dept | Item | Qty | Cost | Receiver | Sender

Ex: 1 | 2018-01-06    | 35   | Milk | 36  | 1.96 | 07       | 02
```

I get the information into the database fine.  The stores and departments are all just numbers.  My problem comes when trying to program the summary report that goes to the accountant to report the necessary numbers.

To create the summary report, I need to pull the information back out of the database and drop it into one of 7 arrays (one for each store).  These arrays would consist of 14 elements (one for each department within the store).  If a store sends out product from department 35 (as in example above), we need to subtract the specified amount from the element for department 35.  If a store receives the product, we need to add the amount to the element for department 35.

I know exactly what I need to do, but I am just not getting any code to work. I have tried various things that I have found here and on other sites.  Unfortunately, this one is a bit above my novice abilities.  Here is where I am at so far, but I am honestly lost as to where to go from here.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Transfers WHERE (tDate BETWEEN '$date1' AND '$date2') ORDER BY tDate ASC";

if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
  if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $send = $row['Sender'];
        $recv = $row['Receiver'];
        $dept = $row['Dept'];
        $qty = $row['Qty'];
        $cost = $row['Cost'];

        // Calculate total line cost
        $totalCost = $qty * $cost;

        $tSender = join($send, $dept);

        $tReceiver = join($recv, $dept);
```

How do I actually take this information and add or subtract it into the arrays for each store?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you should first try a bit more. There are loads of examples out there, also on StackOverflow. Many deal with arrays, which is quite obvious when querying a database. For now this question is way too broad. If you have a *specific* issue, provide the code you have and where you have an issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's just like you surmised. It should be something like that :

```
$resultat=array();
for each result of your request{
  if(!isset($resultat[receiver][dept][item]))$resultat[receiver][dept][item]=array('qty'=>0,'cost'=>0);
  if(!isset($resultat[sender][dept][item]))$resultat[sender][dept][item]=array('qty'=>0,'cost'=>0);
  $resultat[receiver][dept][item]['qty']+=qty;
  $resultat[receiver][dept][item]['cost']+=cost*qty;
  $resultat[sender][dept][item]['qty']-=qty;
  $resultat[sender][dept][item]['cost']-=cost*qty;
}
```

Not usable as is, but it should put you back on track.

Comment: This code makes a ton of assumptions. That quadruple deep structure is really strange.

Comment: It's a given that I had to make some assumptions but I don't find them far-fetched. Plus OP asked for directions, he should be able to adapt this to its needs even if i'm not spot-on. As for the quadruple deep structure, well I like it when it's neatly sorted ^^ (and it's one good way to "print the array for each store and it will already have the totals for each department").

Comment: It's really not clear how this approach would be usable by anyone.